# a recursive and dificult sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove that this sequence converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58019/how-to-prove-that-this-sequence-converges)

Let the sequence defined recursively by the equation:
$$
a_n  = a_{a_{n - 1} }  + a_{n - a_{n - 1} } 
$$
How can I prove that $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{a_n }}
{n}
$$

EDIT: $ a_0 = a_1 = 1 $  Thanks

Comment: The question is incomplete. (1) What are you trying to prove about the limit? (2) Are there any initial conditions on the sequence? (I’m not sure why you’re asking: you’ve not accepted an answer to any of your five previous questions.)

Comment: @Brian: If you're interested in some context and background on this sequence, look at David Speyer's answer in the link I gave above.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks. Willie’s comment is correct (hence my answer below, though I wasn’t aware of the earlier question at that time). The Kubo/Vakil paper sounds interesting; I’ll have to see if I can dig up a copy. (I just retired, so I’ve lost my electronic access through the university, at least until my emeritus status goes through.)

Comment: So trivial is the problem? If this is the case, sorry for be so stupid

Comment: I download it , thx

Answer (score 3):

If you calculate the first few terms of the sequence, you should very easily be able to conjecture a closed form for $a_n$ that works for all $n>0$. Proving the conjecture is an easy exercise in mathematical induction. And once you have that, the value of the limit is obvious.